# The best way to do it is (to make / by making) him friend

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, gerunds, to-infinitive

Which of the following sentence choices is correct? I guess both are. But is there a difference between them?

> The best way to destroy your enemy is **to make** him friend.
>
> The best way to destroy your enemy is **by making** him friend.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94091/discussion-on-question-by-user55625-the-best-way-to-do-it-is-to-make-by-makin).

Answer (score 4):

1) The best way to destroy your enemy is **to make him a friend.**

2) The best way to destroy your enemy is **by making him a friend.**

The first sentence sets up a relationship between the first and second part.

The best way to do something = make x something.

**The "to" is a function word that allows the two parts to relate to each other.** I**t connects the two ideas as a general proposition**. "to" can often refer to purpose or outcome of something as well.

- He went to school to get a diploma.

> Here is proof of this from the British Council:  We use the
>   to-infinitive: to express purpose (to answer "Why...?"): [to plus an
>   infinitive](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/infinitives)

It does not refer to how like the word ***by.***

The second sentence with by refers to a process for doing something or how something is done.

For example:

- I made a cake by baking it.
- He finished the essay by just writing it.
- They worked all night by making an effort.

So, ***by*** introduces the idea of how to do something.

"By making him your friend" refers to the process or activity you engage in.

- They made enemies of their classmates by being so mean to them.

> Here's the proof of this from an online grammar site:

**Method— by verb-ing vs. Instrument— with (a) noun

> METHOD A method of doing something can be expressed with a
>   prepositional phrase that includes by + a gerund. (The prep. phrase is
>   an "adjunct" to the main clause because the sentence can be considered
>   complete without it.)**
>
> You can open it **by using a knife.**

[by plus a gerund](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/gerund3.html)

Comment: dvTer, you should give a reason. Not one person besides myself has even addressed the main issue here.